# Swift, Horizontal scroll view of Images like UIPicker

Tags: swift, uiview, ios8, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I would like to create an image picker as shown in the picture below for iOS 8 using swift. What is the best way to achieve this?
The screen should show the current image on the center and the next and previous images on its sides. On swipe, the images should change. It will be helpful if someone can point to an existing code similar to this.
Thanks

[image]